# Wordpress - Get the taxonomy of a post hierarchically

Tags: hierarchy, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I would like to get all the taxonomy of one post (in a loop), hierarchically. Example I have those taxonomies, and the ID of the tax in bracket.

```
Tax1(1)
-Tax2(3)
--Tax3(2)
```

I would like to gather them, in an array maybe, in this order. Right now I manage to get an array of those 3, but the order is wrong. I can't order it by id, since the ID are not ordered at first. I can't also order it by name and slug. (Names of my current taxonomies are not Tax1, Tax2...)

The code I have at the moment is

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'term_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
$productcategories = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'guide_type', $args);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "Wordpress" **[Walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)** class to create a hierarchy of the taxonomy

```
<?php
class Walker_Quickstart extends Walker {

    // Tell Walker where to inherit it's parent and id values
    var $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'parent', 
        'id'     => 'term_id' 
    );

    /**
     * At the start of each element, output a <p> tag structure.
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $output .= sprintf( "\n<p>%s %s (%s)</p>\n",
            str_repeat('&dash;', $depth),
            $item->name,
            $item->term_id            
        );
    }

}?>
```

This class will create a hierarchy of elements. Use this class with your returned elements like this :

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'term_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
$productcategories = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'guide_type', $args);
$walk = new Walker_Quickstart();
echo $walk->walk($productcategories, 0);
```

Comment: WoW, this is a great answer, ive been stuck on this for like 5 hours. I was about to manage to get something done, but I think your answer is better. Ill post mine as an answer also if you want to take a look. Tanks mate !

Comment: This is a great answer. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Was about to get something with this function that I made, But Vikash Kumar gave me a better answer, thanks !

```
function get_term_top_most_parent($post_id, $taxonomy){
    $return = array();
    $registeredcat = 0;
    $newparent = '';


    $catcount = 0;
    $firstlevels = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy); //post id, taxo, args
    foreach ($firstlevels as $key => $value){
        if($value->parent == 0 ){
            //$firstlevel = $value->term_id; //23
            $newparent = $value->term_id;
            array_push($return, $value);
            $registeredcat += 1;
        }
        $catcount += 1;
    }
return $return;
}
```